# Maven: How to add a patched dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho, p2

I am building eclipse plugins with maven, for eclipse oxygen 3.
My maven configuration uses following repository.

```
<repository>
       <id>eclipse</id>
       <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201705151400/</url>
       <layout>p2</layout>
</repository>
```

And one of my plugins depends on our custom patched version of `org.eclipse.tcf.te.tcf.launch.cdt` that exists in this repository.

I would like to specify in my maven to use patched version of this plugin for solving it's dependency.
How should I do it? Suppose I have a local separated P2 repo that has this only patch.

If I am adding a new repository, the build still fails.

```
<repository>
         <id>TCF</id>
         <url>file:<my_path>/tcf_patch-1.5.0.v20181116</url>
         <layout>p2</layout>
</repository>
```

Comment: You mistake the idea of Eclipse repository with Maven repository

Comment: If you have a patched dependency you would more likely benefit from including it within the project and installing it manually.

Comment: That's what I wouldn't like to do 'Compass', if I understood correctly. I am integrating the workflow in jenkins, I will have a jenkins job that will checkout sources and run maven for build, and during build it should know to use patched plugin for solving dependency. I can not add sources for tcf open sources plugin in my repo.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
I have solved my problem, and my original attempt to solve it was correct. Just the patch I used was wrong.
So, basically it is sufficient for maven.
If Original plugins are accessible from

```
<repository>
       <id>eclipse</id>
       <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201804111000</url>
       <layout>p2</layout>
</repository>
```

And my patch resides in

```
 <repository>
         <id>TCF</id>
         <url>file: ../TCF_PATCH_20181116</url>
         <layout>p2</layout>
 </repository>
```

Maven is able to apply latest version of eclipse plugins available from provided repositories for solving dependencies. Cool ;)